# How to connecting PC desktop to Miracast

Tags: miracast

I want to connecting my devices to the projector Display (infocus) using Wireless Display Adapter (Wecast Miracast).

a. When Connecting Smartphone to Miracast, sucessfully without any problems

b. Connecting Notebook/laptop (Windows 10) to Miracast, sucessfully without any problems

c. But when I want to Connecting Personal Computer (Windows 10) to Miracast, not successfully. I use USB Wifi Adapter TP Link TL-WN722N. Wifi successfully paired.

give me suggestions. 
thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the tp link WLAN Adapter 722n does not support Miracast, even the new driver does not help. Sorry for that.

BR
Ben